# Elementor's color optoin is not working on an actual page

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

I've assigned a new custom widget and I added a control:

```
$this->add_control(
        'text_color',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Text Color', 'textdomain' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
            'selectors' => [
                '{{WRAPPER}}  .your-caption' => 'color: {{VALUE}}',
            ],
            'default'=> '#fff',
        ]
    );
```

However, such color change is working only in the builder itself, not on an actual page.

I've flushed caches, made sure there's no CSS conflicts (In fact, such color or CSS is nowhere to be seen once I inspect elements)

Any idea what might be wrong?